# Create instances with changing class names

Tags: c#, reflection

I want to call many tests like this.

```
        var test8001 = new Test8001();
        test8001.Execute(drv);
        var test8002 = new Test8002();
        test8002.Execute(drv);
        var test8007 = new Test8007();
        test8007.Execute(drv);
```

How can I automatically instantiate all test function with a int list of all test numbers?

```
        List<int> classNameNumbers = new List<int>() { 8001, 8002, 8007 };
```

I need a for-loop where Execute() is called on every instance.

Edit:
The name of the type e.g. 'Test8001' should be retrieved from my integer list.

Comment: Build a simple console application that generates the code in a txt file, then copy/paste that generated code into your actual application. 9 times out of 10, if you're a relatively competent developer, it's easier to write a text generation tool yourself, compared to learning to use a tool someone else has created (unless you want to generate **really** complex code, which this example is not)

Comment: Note that I could have also suggested reflection, but I think you're not really interested in generating the tests at runtime, you're just looking for a way to generate code before compile time. If I misunderstood that, my earlier comment does not apply and reflection would be the way to go.

Comment: You're passing a parameter to only one of those tests?

Comment: If these are actually unit tests, consider using an actual test framework.

Comment: I think I will need reflection. I dont want to copy and paste anything. - drv is used in all the tests now (Edit).

Comment: @Blorgbeard No this aren't only unit tests. I made my own test system.

Comment: Reflection will work but it won't be pretty. If a class doesn't have the right name or the method doesn't have the right signature it will throw an exception or fail silently. That's something we don't want in production code, but we have to maintain our tests just like we have to maintain production code. TBH I'd take it as a reason to rethink why the tests need to be run this way.

Comment: Depending on what you want to do with the results, you can try compiling string generated in code with Roslyn: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn

Comment: Do the tests need to be run in order? If not, you could give them meaningful names, have them all implement an interface `ITest`. You could then use reflection to find all implementors of `ITest`. Then you don't have to use reflection for the method call, you can just cast each instance to `ITest`.

Comment: For something this simple you could even "generate" the code in a few seconds using Excel. `="new Test" & TEXT(A1, "0") & "().Execute(drv);"` That avoids the tenuous link between a set of numbers and corresponding classes which may or may not exist.

Comment: but hundreds of tests will follow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out the following

```
namespace Stackoverflow46529447
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var drv = new Drv();

            var numbers = new[] {8001, 8002, 8003};
            var executables = numbers.Select(x => Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType($"Stackoverflow46529447.Test{x:0000}")))
                .OfType<IExecutable>()
                .ToArray();

            foreach (var executable in executables)
            {
                executable.Execute(drv);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Test8001 : IExecutable
    {
        public void Execute(Drv drv)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello from Test 8001");
        }
    }

    public class Test8002 : IExecutable
    {
        public void Execute(Drv drv)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello from Test 8002");
        }
    }

    public class Test8003 : IExecutable
    {
        public void Execute(Drv drv)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello from Test 8003");
        }
    }

    public interface IExecutable
    {
        void Execute(Drv drv);
    }

    public class Drv
    {

    }
}
```

This uses reflection to create instance types.